# Adding a conditional calculated column to a pandas dataframe - a better alternative than iterrows()?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm adding a column to a pandas dataframe, performing calculations on 3 columns based on the categorical data in 2 other columns.
My code is technically working at the moment, but I've read that I should avoid the iterrows fuction as it uses a lot of memory, and is pretty slow.

My code at the moment looks like this:

```
   MatchupScores = []
for index, row in SynergyTable.iterrows():
    if (row['role'] == 'AD' and row['AllyPosition'] == 'Support') or (row['role'] == 'Support' and row['AllyPosition'] == 'AD'):
        MatchupScore = (row['WinRate'] - 50 + row['Delta1'] + row['Delta2'])/2
    else:
        MatchupScore = (row['WinRate'] - 50 + row['Delta1'] + row['Delta2'])/3
    MatchupScores.append(MatchupScore)
SynergyTable['MatchupScores'] = MatchupScores
```

What alternative methods do should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, this would be the same, and much faster:

```
mask = ((df['role'].eq('AD') & df['AllyPosition'].eq('Support')) |
        (df['role'].eq('Support') & df['AllyPosition'].eq('AD')))

base_calc = df['WinRate'].sub(50).add(df['Delta1']).add(df['Delta2'])

df.loc[mask, 'MatchupScores'] = base_calc.loc[mask].div(2)
df.loc[~mask, 'MatchupScores'] = base_calc.loc[~mask].div(3)
```

See [Boolean Indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) in the documentation~ If you can use Boolean Indexing, and purely vectorized functions, you'll have the best performance.

---

If you can't figure out the correct vectorized method, *at least* implement your current solution like so, using `apply`:

```
def update_MatchupScore(row):
    if (row['role'] == 'AD' and row['AllyPosition'] == 'Support') or (row['role'] == 'Support' and row['AllyPosition'] == 'AD'):
        return (row['WinRate'] - 50 + row['Delta1'] + row['Delta2'])/2
    else:
        return (row['WinRate'] - 50 + row['Delta1'] + row['Delta2'])/3

SynergyTable['MatchupScores'] = SynergyTable.apply(update_MatchupScore, axis=1)
```